# ImageViewer Together with TextView PREV and NEXT

Tags: android

so I made an ImageViewer on my app, that uses counting to go through all the pictures. By using the next and prev button. Now I'm trying to add a textview to go with it. So I made another textview under it, and tried this code:

```
   View.OnClickListener nButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Increase Counter to move to next Image
            currentImage--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

            imageView.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
            if(currentImage == img1){
                textView4.setText("My Awesome Text");
            }

        }
    };
```

UPDATE: I tried this, but yeah still wouldn't work.

View.OnClickListener nButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Increase Counter to move to next Image
    currentImage--;
    currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;
     String img1 = "img1";
    String comparable = imageView.toString();
    imageView.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
    if(comparable == img1){
        textView4.setText("My Awesome Text");
    }

}
```

};

This is the listener for my next and prev button. I figured out that using the if statement, `if(currentImage == img1)` I could match the textview to its own image. Let's say for img1 I'll set it to "Awesome text"

Unfortunately, it won't work, I thought of making `currentImage` as a string but it's not allowed. What's another approach to this? or perhaps what did I do wrong on the snippet?

Comment: Please elaborate - do you need a different text for each image, or you need the same text for just some images,  or is it something else.

Comment: I needed different text for each image. I found a nice appraoch with rekts answer, however I would also like to hear about yours. Mr. @colens since the one he posted had a little bit of error. Like the text not matching the image.  but yeah its definitely switching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are quite in a trouble eh. Try to think out of the box young'un!

I bet you're using an integer in order to go through your list. Like that currentImage set to 0.

So here's another appraoch so listen,

set another integer, let's say:

```
private int currentText = 0;
```

then:

```
  View.OnClickListener bButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Increase Counter to move to next Image
            currentImage++;
            currentText++;
            currentImage = currentImage % images.length;

            imageView.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
            if (currentText == 1)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText");
            }
            if (currentText == 2)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText1");
            }

            if (currentText == 0)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText2");
            }


        }
    };



    View.OnClickListener nButtonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Increase Counter to move to next Image
            currentImage--;
            currentText--;
            currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length;

            if (currentText == 1)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText");
            }
            if (currentText == 2)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText1");
            }

            if (currentText == 0)
            {
                textView4.setText("AwesomeText2");
            }








        }
    };
```

Well something along those lines!

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution where you keep your text references in an array of the same lenght as the image array:

```
  View.OnClickListener buttonChangeImageListener = new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Increase Counter to move to next Image and Text
        current++;
        current = current % images.length;

        imageView.setImageResource(images[current]);
        textView4.setText(texts[current]);


    }
};
```

**EDIT:**
One way to define **texts** array is:

```
String []texts = {"Text1","Text2",...,"TextN"};
```

So the array will have as many strings as there are pictures.

The other way is to define strings in Resorces (like you did with pictures). Add a new file under res/values and call it for example **texts.xml**. 
texts.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="text1">This is text 1</string>
    <string name="text2">This is text 2</string>
     ....
    <string name="textN">This is text N</string>
</resources>
```

Then in your code

```
int [] texts = {R.string.text1, R.string.text2,...,R.string.textN} ;
```

To get texts:

```
textView4.setText(getResources().getString(texts[current]));
```

Comment: this is indeed shorter sir, how do I put my texts in a list? for images I did this `    int[] images = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3 };` I was able to do this because they were drawables, how about texts?